# Orgmode set font face on per file basis

Tags: org-mode

is there a way to set the font attributes on per file basis? I'm surprised this is not a main feature... I don't want my todo lists to look the same as my articles or journal.

IF there is such a thing is there also something like importing? e.g. `import 'article_style'`?

I tried the following without success

```
;; Local Variables:
;; eval: '(org-level-1 ((t (:weight thin :height 1.6 :family "Helvetica Neue"))))
;; End:
```

Comment: I'm not surprised that it doesn't do anything, since the result of evaluating a quoted list is simply to return the list.  In other words, you have not told emacs to do anything.  You would need to wrap that statement in a call to `custom-set-faces` if you wanted it to do something.  However, this will change the face globally, which is obviously not what you want in this case.

Comment: Looking around, I would say that https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local might be your best bet.  You could define your own themes in your .emacs file, and then load them from the file-local variables.